# Compare two sql outputs

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table, which has to resemble an annual song chart. It contains 2000 songs and their position per year, ranging from 1999 to 2014.

I have to show all the songs that have gone up in the charts the next year

the table contains an SONGID (PK, FK, int, not null) LISTYEAR(PK, int, not null) and POSITION(int, not null)

The goal is to write an stored procedure with 1 given parameter, a year to compare with the (self generated) next year and show the songs that has been gone up in the chart.

For example:

The user passes the value '2012' for the variable @firstyear to the stored procedure.

The server then takes the variable and adds one to put it in the next variable @secondyear, which then should be 2013 of course.

There should be an output with just one table, which should have 'Songname' 'Position in @firstyear' and 'Position in @secondyear' as headers.

The value 'position in @secondyear' should always be higher than the 'position in @firstyear' because it only has to show the songs that went up.

How can I achieve this? Is there a method in mssql to compare the values inside 1 table?

EDIT:

dumb of me to not provide you with example data:

http://puu.sh/iihTc/4518dbcea9.png <- the database diagram

http://puu.sh/iii2r/a04d639f2c.png <- some example data in those three tables

output example will be in comment

note that only the songs may be outputted which climbed up in rank

Comment: Not clear exactly, Show some sample data and expected output

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: I don't think you need the SecondYear parameter. From what I can understand of your question you are going to have to create a temp table for your @firstyear parameter, then you will set Atfirstyear to the years your interested within your temp. Join the temp to your main query and then the years will cycle through what they've been set to. I can post an example answer, I didn't because I'm not very famliar with mssql.

Comment: added example data in post, example output: http://puu.sh/iiiAM/987bfeb159.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this

```
declare @year as int = 2011
select a.songid, a.position, b.position from YourTable a
inner join YourTable b on a.songid = b.songid
where a.YEAR = @year and b.year = @year + 1 and a.position > b.position
```

See below, Only song 2 has moved up from 2011 to 2012, so showing in result

[image]

Comment: Your answer looks promising though. Gonna try That one this evening

Comment: Great, try and let me know the result.

Comment: You are my hero, exactly what i am looking for! Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would not use variables for this. I'd join the table back onto itself. If you're working with very large data sets (hundreds of millions of rows) you may want to performance test both ways to be sure, but `JOIN`ing the table back to itself makes more sense to me.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.AnnualSongChart 
(
    SongID INT NOT NULL
    , ListYear INT NOT NULL
    , Position INT NOT NULL
    , SongName VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.AnnualSongChart(SongID, ListYear, Position, SongName)
SELECT 1, 2012, 14, 'Grieg: Peer Gynt: In The Hall of the Mountain King'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2013, 15, 'Grieg: Peer Gynt: In The Hall of the Mountain King'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2012, 12, 'Wagner: Die Walkure'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2013, 11, 'Wagner: Die Walkure'

--Code to pull your report
SELECT DISTINCT
    CurrentYear.ListYear
    , CurrentYear.SongName
    , CurrentYear.Position 
FROM dbo.AnnualSongChart CurrentYear
JOIN dbo.AnnualSongChart LastYear
ON 
    CurrentYear.ListYear = LastYear.ListYear + 1
    AND CurrentYear.SongID = LastYear.SongID
WHERE 
    CurrentYear.Position < LastYear.Position 
    -- AND CurrentYear.ListYear = 2013
```

If you'd only like to get data for a certain year, enable the `WHERE` clause criteria to the year you want to pull for. Note, this is all speculation as your original question does not include table definitions or example data. Please edit your original question if this does not give you the output you're looking for.